# Идентичны ли понятия?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Идентичны ли понятия "территориальная общность языков" и "общность их происхождения"? Аргументируйте, пожалуйста, ответ, иллюстрируя примерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Эти понятия не идентичны. Сходство языков иногда обнаруживается у народов, живущих далеко друг от друга и давно уже не общающихся между собой. Примеры:***   **1.** Похожи язык венгров и языки двух маленьких народностей Западной Сибири — хантов и манси. Когда-то в далеком прошлом их предки жили вместе. От этого далекого прошлого осталось языковое сходство, которое постепенно ослабевало, так как на протяжении длительного времени языки эти развивались и изменялись отдельно один от другого. **2.** На языках одной и той же тюркской группы говорили многие народы разных районов Советского Союза — Средней Азии, Поволжья, Сибири, а также и некоторых зарубежных стран.

Comment: А сколько здесь примеров?

Comment: Некоторое количество.)

Comment: После двоеточия они отделяются тчк/зпт или нумеруются.

Comment: Имейте уже покой, гражанин shampar.)

Comment: Пишите на обоях — слова не скажу. Хоть курсивом, хоть вязью.

Comment: Да Вы просто Мороз-воевода какой-то.)

Comment: Есть повод перехода на личности вместо правки? И повод — незнание числа примеров?

Answer (score 3):

Названия говорят сами за себя. Территориальная общность -языки на одной территории, общность происхождения - от одного праязыка.

Светлана, у Вас же перечень литературы есть. Откройте Реформатского.

Генеалоги́ческая классифика́ция языко́в —
изучение и группировка языков мира на основании определения родственных связей между ними (отнесения их к одной семье, группе), т. е. на основе общего происхождения из предполагаемого праязыка. Каждая семья происходит из разошедшихся друг с другом диалектов одного языка (праязыка этой семьи), например, все романские языки происходят из диалектов народной (вульгарной) латыни, на которых говорила большая часть населения Римской империи перед её распадом

http://tapemark.narod.ru/les/093d.html

http://philologos.narod.ru/ling/ref_familytr.htm

А.А. Реформатский

I. ИНДОЕВРОПЕЙСКИЕ ЯЗЫКИ:
•   Индийская группа
•   Иранская группа
•   Славянская группа
•   Балтийская группа
•   Германская группа
•   Романская группа
•   Кельтская группа
•   Греческая группа
•   Албанская группа
•   Армянская группа
•   Хетто-лувийская (анатолийская) группа
•   Тохарская группа

II. КАВКАЗСКИЕ ЯЗЫКИ

•   А. Западная группа: абхазско-адыгские языки

•   Б. Восточная группа: нахско-дагестанские языки

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не идентичны. Например, как правильно заметил @Матвей Дёмин, венгры и ханты говорят на угорских языках, хотя живут довольно далеко друг от друга. Тут мы имеем дело с *общностью их происхождения*, то есть они связаны между собой **генетически**. А вот кавказские языки — это территориальная (или *географическая*) общность языков, которая подразумевает, возможно, их некоторое взаимодействие, однако **родственными они не являются**.